# Placing images on top of other images in wxpython

Tags: image, wxpython, redraw

I know this question is pretty basic, and I'm sorry for posting it, but I literally have spent the last hour googling and I still havent found an answer.

I coded a blackjack game using pygame, and want to convert it to wxpython mostly as a way to learn wxpython. In pygame the graphics are easy, I have a base image I display (basically just the table), and then I can just display other images on top of it as the action unfolds, for example the cards. Each time the player hits I just draw a new card in a different position. When The hand is over and I want to go to the next hand, I just display the base image again, and it covers everything up and viola! Its really simple all I have to use is blit() and pygame.display.update().

I cant seem to find anyway to do this in wxpython. All the examples I find are for drawing items in new widgets, or drawing vector graphics over an image, or opening new frames with images, etc.

any help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

--Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post, which reading the comments, does a good job of showing me want I was looking for.

[Delete image in wxpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071613/delete-image-in-wxpython)

Answer (score 0):

The AlphaDrawing example in the wxPython demo shows how to overlap multiple drawings. This uses wx.GraphicContext / wx.GCDC. If you look at the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GraphicsContext.html), you'll note that it has CreateBitmapFromImage and CreateBitmap methods that probably apply to what you want to do. See also the DragImage demo and the following links for related information:

- [wx python card game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622884/wx-python-card-game)
- http://rummy-py.sourceforge.net/ (look at the original that was done in wx)

Comment: Mike, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Going through those links was helpful for my overall learning of wxpython. much appreciated